# Set up MySQL@5.7 on Mac

Tags: mysql, laravel, homebrew

I set up Laravel Valet on my Mac and installed mysql which is 8.* version. I have projects with Laravel 5.4 which doesn't support mysql 8.* version. How can I set up mysql 5.7 version on Mac? Preferably with homebrew.

Comment: You could set up a mysql57 container easily with docker. Doing this would mean you don't have to keep reinstalling mysql when you want a different version.

Comment: @JimWright maybe you could write the command? I'm not good with docker, but I do have it installed

Comment: Instructions are on https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You can install MySQL 5.7 by Homebrew with:

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```